# If a measure $\mu$ is differentiable at $x_0$ then $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. The upper derivative of $\mu$ is defined as:

$$\bar{D}\mu(x)=\limsup_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left\{ \frac{\mu(C)}{\lambda(C)}: x\in C \in \mathcal{C}, e(C)<\epsilon \right\}$$

where $\mathcal{C}$ is the familly of closed cubes with edges parallel to coordinate axis and $e(C)$ the length of the edge of the cube.
In the same way the lower derivative is defined as 
$$\underline{D}\mu(x)=\liminf_{\epsilon\to0^+}\left\{\frac{\mu(C)}{\lambda(C)}: x\in C \in \mathcal{C}, e(C)<\epsilon \right\}.$$

$\mu$ is said to be differentiable at $x_0$ if $\bar{D}\mu(x_0)=\underline{D}\mu(x_0)$.

If $\mu$ is differentiable at $x_0$, $\mu(\{x_0\})=0$, but I don't see how to show it. If someone can help me I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you assume that $\bar{D}\mu(x_0) = \underline{D}\mu(x_0)$ is **finite**. (Otherwise the assertion does not hold true; just consider e.g. $\mu = \delta_{x_0}$, then $\bar{D}\mu(x_0)  = \underline{D}\mu(x_0)=\infty$.)

Let $\mu$ be a  finite measure such that $\mu(\{x_0\})>0$ for some fixed $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}^d$. If we set $C_n := x_0 + [0,1/n]^d$, then

$$\frac{\mu(C_n)}{\lambda(C_n)} \geq \frac{\mu(\{x_0\})}{1/n^d} \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} \infty$$

and therefore

$$\bar{D}\mu(\{x_0\}) = \infty.$$

This proves $$\mu(\{x_0\})>0 \implies \bar{D}\mu(\{x_0\})=\infty$$ which is equivalent to saying $$\bar{D}\mu(\{x_0\})<\infty \implies \mu(\{x_0\})=0.$$

Comment: This may be a stupid question but this whole thing with taking supremum and infimum over sets that include $x_0$ confuses me (I feel like $\{x_0\}$ should be the smallest such set since it's a measure?); is it obvious that $\frac{\mu(C_n)}{\lambda(C_n)} \geq \frac{\mu(\{x_0\})}{1/n^d} $ ?

Comment: @user202542 1. By the monotonicity of the measure $\mu(C_n) \geq \mu(\{x_0\})$; $\lambda(C_n) = 1/n^d$ follows directly from the definition of the Lebesgue measure. 2. Note that for $C:=\{x_0\}$ the expression $\mu(C)/\lambda(C)$ is not well-defined.